How to onboard kafka application which has TCP call
We have application which will read messages from kafka. Here it has transaction or calls with TCP not http. Transactions which are with TCP not coming to elastic APM.
Could you please suggest what has to do ? Do we have any attribute to add and which helps to get transactions?
